# Jenkins : Error 403 No valid crumb was included in the request : From TFS

Tags: jenkins, tfs

I have a TFS build that uses a service connection to Jenkins, which contains the username and password (that connection appears to be working when I test it from TFS).
The build itself uses a "Jenkins Queue Job" task, where I provide the job name and any parameters that it might need.
This was working fine up until recently, when Jenkins is now returning :

```
Error 403 No valid crumb was included in the request</title>\n</head>\n<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 403 No valid crumb was included in the request
```

It looks like the connection is working, and I cannot see any way that I can provide that crumb?

Comment: Have you done Jenkins version upgrade, what do you mean by "This was working fine up until recently"? What change caused this?

Comment: Yes it looks like Jenkins was updated by the team that manages it. To version 2.228?

Answer (score 5):

We had similar issue after upgrade from 2.94 to 2.201.

From https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/219257077-CSRF-Protection-Explained:

> If you authenticate your API calls with a username and a user API
>   token then a crumb is not required from Jenkins 2.96

Our solution was:
1. Jenkins admin had to generate API token for the user in TFS;
2. Then someone with enough permissions for TFS services endpoints had to replace this user password with the API token (figure 9 [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/vsts-visual-studio-team-services-integration-with-jenkins/)).

Comment: For steps on how to generate API tokens on Jenkins: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45466090/how-to-get-the-api-token-for-jenkins

Answer (score 4):

Your issue may be caused by [CSRF protection](https://jenkins.io/security/advisory/2019-08-28/#SECURITY-1491) in Jenkins Server. You may try the solution in case [Jenkins 2.192: HTTP Error 403: No valid crumb was included in the request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57731818/jenkins-2-192-http-error-403-no-valid-crumb-was-included-in-the-request):

1. Install the Strict Crumb Issuer plugin (https://plugins.jenkins.io/strict-crumb-issuer/)
2. Enable this plugin and uncheck 'Check the session ID' from its configuration (Under Jenkins Configure Global Security)