# SVN post commit hook is giving 403 forbidden while triggering Jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, svn

I am trying to implement my post commit hook from my SVN repo to trigger one Jenkins job for my spring boot microservice deployment. But when I am committing code change, its committing to SVN repository. But its not triggering Jenkins job and giving error like 403 forbidden and it showing post commit hook failed with error code 8 on dialog box,

I am getting error like the following:

[image]

My post commit hook file **post-commit** like the following (I was removed post-commit.tmpl and created new post-commit file and added content here):

[image]

And My Jenkins freestyle jobs like the following:

[image]

[image]

**NB: Code change are successfully committing to SVN repository. Problem is when triggering the Jenkins job.**

Have I made a mistake in any of my implementation?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you hit the CSRF (Cross Site Request Forgery) Jenkins protection.

> CSRF protection uses a token (called crumb in Jenkins) that is created
> by Jenkins and sent to the user. Any form submissions or similar
> action resulting in modifications, like triggering builds or changing
> configuration, requires that the crumb be provided.

> Requests sent using the POST method are subject to CSRF protection in Jenkins >and generally need to provide a crumb.

If you have administrator permissions, you can configure CSRF Protection through Manage Jenkins » Configure Global Security » CSRF Protection.

If you authenticate your API calls with a username and a **user API token** then a crumb is not required from Jenkins 2.96. So you can:

1. Generate API token from Jenkins (admin permissions needed).
2. Then use the API token instead of password for your calls.

Reference:
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/security/csrf-protection/
[Jenkins : Error 403 No valid crumb was included in the request : From TFS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60893716/jenkins-error-403-no-valid-crumb-was-included-in-the-request-from-tfs)
https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/219257077-CSRF-Protection-Explained
[Jenkins: 403 No valid crumb was included in the request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44711696/jenkins-403-no-valid-crumb-was-included-in-the-request)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a permission issue. See the [subversion plugin documentation](https://plugins.jenkins.io/subversion/):

> For this to work, **your Jenkins has to allow anonymous read access** (specifically, "Job > Read" access) to the system. If access control to your Jenkins is more restrictive, **you may need to specify the username and password**, depending on how your authentication is configured.